# Having problems converting from nested for loop to nested while loop

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert this nested for loop to nested while loop:

The program:

```
#include<iostream>
   using namespace std;
   void main()
   {
    int i,j,n,stars=1;
    cout<<"Enter the number of rows:";
    cin>>n;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<=stars;j++)
            cout<<"*";
    cout<<"\n";
            stars=stars+1;
    }

   }
```

While Trying the nested while loop the loop doesn't stop can someone please give me the solution?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
int n,i,j,k,stars=1;
   cout<<"Enter the number of rows";
   cin>>n;
    i=1;
    while(i<=n)
    {
    j=1;
    while(j<=stars)
    {
        cout<<"*";
        cout<<"\n";
        stars=stars+1;
    }
    j=j+1;
}
i=i+1;

}
```

Comment: Just move `j=j+1;` inside your inner while loop.

Comment: Don't do this: `int n,i,j,k,stars=1;`, please. And use a space-bar.

Comment: C++ - `void main` - please (also using `using std` - that is a bad idea)

Answer (score 2):

You have to incement your control varibales `i` ans `j` inside your loops. You did it outsid the loops directly after. Apart from this the varibale `stars` was incremented in the outer `for` loop. In the secend code snippet you did it in the inner `while` loop.  Adapt your code like this:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cout<<"Enter the number of rows";
    std::cin>>n;
    int stars=1;
    int i=1;
    while ( i<=n )         // corresponds to for(i=1;i<=n;i++) { .... }
    {
        int j=1;
        while ( j<=stars ) // corresponds to for(j=1;j<=stars;j++) cout<<"*";
        {
            std::cout<<"*";
            j++;           // increment control variable inside of the loop  
        }

        std::cout<<"\n";
        stars++;
        i++;               // increment control variable inside of the loop    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note if you improve the formatting of the code, you'll find such mistakes easily.